# Conflito em templates visualização de listas personalizados no Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

## Problema

Tenho duas listas customizadas com `ListTemplateType = 100`. Quando insiro as duas em uma página a última sobrescreve a primeira, então ela deixa de funcionar, funcionando apenas a última.

Tentei adicionar o `BaseViewID` com ID's diferentes para ambas, conforme vi [nesta pergunta](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115536/js-link-2-different-templates-for-2-different-views-of-same-list-on-1-page). Porém, agora nenhum dos dois templates está funcionando. Antes apenas o último não exibia nada, agora ambos estão exibindo a listagem padrão do Sharepoint.

#### Template 1 `app1-jslink.js`

```
;(function(){
    overrideCtx.Templates.Header = "<div id='gallery-cardapio'>"+
            "<div class='gallery-cardapio'>"+
                "<ul class='thumbs'>";
    overrideCtx.Templates.Footer = CustomFooter;
    overrideCtx.BaseViewID = 1000;
    overrideCtx.ListTemplateType = 100;

    overrideCtx.Templates.Item = CustomItem;

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);

    function CustomItem(ctx){...}

    function CustomFooter(ctx){...}
})();
```

#### Template 2 `app2-jslink.js`

```
;(function(){
    overrideCtx.Templates.Header = "<div id='gallery-niver'>"+
            "<div class='gallery-container'>"+
                "<ul class='thumbs'>";
    overrideCtx.Templates.Footer = CustomFooter;
    overrideCtx.BaseViewID = 900;
    overrideCtx.ListTemplateType = 100;

    overrideCtx.Templates.Item = CustomItem;

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);

    function CustomItem(ctx){...}

    function CustomFooter(ctx){...}
})();
```

---

## Testes

Se eu colocar o `BaseViewId` em apenas um, ambos os *templates* serão renderizados com o *override* que não possui o `BaseViewId`.

Se eu colocar o `BaseViewId` nos dois, eles serão renderizados com o template padrão de listagem do Sharepoint.

Se eu não colocar `BaseViewId` em nenhum, ambos serão renderizados com o último *override*.

---

### Como resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi o problema da seguinte forma:

Adicionei um *webpart* do tipo editor de *script* na página com o seguinte código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){

        var oldRenderListView = RenderListView;

        RenderListView = function(ctx,webPartID) {
            if (ctx.wpq == 'WPQ5')
                ctx.BaseViewID = 900;
            else if (ctx.wpq == 'WPQ6')
                ctx.BaseViewID = 1000;

            oldRenderListView(ctx,webPartID);
        }

    },"ClientTemplates.js");
</script>
```

<sub>A função é executada após o script `ClientTemplates.js` ter sido carregado. Ele sobrescreve o `BaseViewId` dos meus template que possuem os códigos `WPQ5` e `WPQ6`.</sub>

### Fontes

- [Pergunta no Sharepoint.StackExchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/144736/jslink-conflict-with-lists-of-the-same-type-list-custom-100/144742#144742)
- [Postagem no MyFatBlog](http://www.myfatblog.co.uk/index.php/2013/09/listview-web-part-issues-with-jslink-and-display-templates-a-solution/)